# Python Regular Expression for Gene Name Extraction

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file:

```
Chr1 0  100 gene49 Gnomon gene  ID=gene49;Name=LOC101947233;Dbxref=GeneID:101947233;gbkey=Gene;gene=LOC444342;part=1%2F1
```

I am trying to extract only the gene name from each line (so I want to extract gene=LOC444342, and that's it.)

I've been using the following regular expression:

```
 gene=.*;
```

However, it keeps extracting the following:

```
gene=LOC444342;part=1%2F1
```

Obviously I dont want anything after the ;.

Any help?

Comment: Add lazy quantifier `.*?` or use a negated character class `[^;]*`. Also, if you're only looking for the value only, you can use `(?<=gene=)` instead of `gene=`

Comment: the `+` and `*` quantifiers are by default greedy, to make them lazy, use `?`, so something like: `re.search(r"gene=.+?;", s)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current regex is **greedy** (`.*`), so it's matching as much as possible (everything after `gene=` and up to the *last occurrence* of `;`). You can make your `.*` lazy by adding the lazy quantifier `?` as such: `.*?`. There exists, however, better options (reducing the number of steps until a match is found) since lazy quantifiers backtrack.

**Option 1**

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/4cPl1V/1)

```
(?<=gene=)[^;]+
```

- `(?<=gene=)` Positive lookbehind ensuring what precedes matches `gene=` literally
- `[^;]+` Match any character except `;` one or more times

Result: `LOC444342`

**Option 2**

Including `gene=` and `;` in the match, you can use the following as [seen in use here](https://regex101.com/r/4cPl1V/2)

```
gene=[^;]*;
```

Result: `gene=LOC444342;`

Comment: As per OP, `gene=` needs to be selected too i think. See my answer.

Comment: @heemayl my answer includes an option to have `gene=` included in the match. I've made it more apparent.

Answer (score 1):

**Using zero-width lookarounds:**

```
(?<=;)gene=[^;]+(?=;)
```

- Positive lookbehind, `(?<=;)`, matches the `;` before `gene=...`
- `gene=[^;]+` matches the desired portion starting from `gene=` upto next `;`
- Zero width positive lookahead, `(?=;)`, makes sure the match is followed by `;`

**Without lookarounds, with captured grouping:**

```
;(gene=[^;]+);
```

Now, you need to get the first (only) captured group.

**Example:**

```
In [4]: str_ = r'Chr1 0  100 gene49 Gnomon gene  ID=gene49;Name=LOC101947233;Dbxref=GeneID:101947233;gbkey=Gene;gene=LOC444342;part=1%2F1'

In [5]: re.search(r'(?<=;)gene=[^;]+(?=;)', str_).group()
Out[5]: 'gene=LOC444342'

In [6]: re.search(r';(gene=[^;]+);', str_).group(1)
Out[6]: 'gene=LOC444342'
```